# Graph API - Create a Team with an tab on the General channel

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm provisioning a new Microsoft Team using the graph beta api and I would like to add an app as a tab to the General Channel. But the documentation only shows adding new tabs to a custom channel.

There is probably a way to add it to the general tab after the team has been created. But ideally I would like to do it in 1 call.

This is the documentation that shows what i'm trying to achieve: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-beta

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? Did you get an error? What exactly is stopping you from achieving the result ? In general, remember to show your work and be specific as possible so that the community can be effective helping you

Comment: That's the thing, there isn't any documentation to follow to get anything on the General channel. The documentation only shows how to create new channels. So there is no error, nothing to try etc.

Comment: Did you manage anything around this? Feel free to nudge us in the right direction of you found something about this.